# Authorization of email

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

We are facing a problem, that we are using our official email by using Gmail Services as shown:

[image: "Send mail as" settings]

Our Problem is when we send an email to Multiple Users/Email IDs, they received Our mail in their ***Spam Folder.***

How we can authorize our official mail to Gmail?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you sign up with Google for Government:   https://www.google.com/work/apps/government/

Any Gmail-based approach will likely always face the problem you describe.